# Reverse geolocation contains empty array. What should I do?

Tags: php, reverse-geocoding

I am new to php and I am developing an application that involves reverse geolocation . I am sending my latitude and longitude from android application. The problems is that I gets value the first but if I try requesting again I get Undefined offset: 0 error.

PHP CODE

```
$geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.$driverLatitude.','.$driverLongitude.'&sensor=false');

           while($geocode == "false"){
            $geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.$driverLatitude.','.$driverLongitude.'&sensor=false');
            sleep(6);
            }
             $data = json_decode($geocode);
             $add_array  = $data->results;

             $add_array =$add_array[0];
             $add_array = $add_array->address_components;
             $country = "Not found";
             $state = "Not found";
             $city = "Not found";
             foreach ($add_array as $key) {
               if($key->types[0] == 'administrative_area_level_2')
               {
                 $city = $key->long_name;
               }
               if($key->types[0] == 'administrative_area_level_1')
               {
                 $state = $key->long_name;
               }
               if($key->types[0] == 'country')
               {
                 $country = $key->long_name;
               }
             }
             echo "Country : ".$country." ,State : ".$state." ,City : ".$city ."<br />";
```

Is there a way I can resend the request after sometime in php till I get a value.

Comment: Do a `while()` loop while `$geocode` is false. Be sure to add delays/short circuits after so many tries.

Comment: @FrankerZ let me try that

Comment: @FrankerZ I have updated my code but it did not work for me